# UICOllectionview, scrolling to first cell that contains in its title an NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a uicollectionview hosting a number of cells, each cell has a title on it.
the same collectionview can have multiple cells that have the same title.
I need to grammatically scroll the collectionview to the first occurrence of a cell which has title  = user selection.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through you data source and find the first object and call then call collection views scrolltoIndexPath method.

```
__block NSIndexPath* indexPath = nil;
[yourDataSource enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isEqualToString:title]) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
if (indexPath) {
//set the scroll position accordingly 
    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:YES];
}
```